# Why is my fan constatnly blowing in Ubuntu?

Tags: fan, fancontrol

I have installed **Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bits)** alongside **Windows 7** on different partition on my second desktop. It's working nice. I have updated everything.

However, **I have problems with my fan**. **It's blowing non-stop and very fast(loud).** I haven't these problems in Windows 7 where it works nicely.

How to update drivers for my fan or something else?

My desktop is:

---

**HP Pro 3410 Microtower PC**.

Graphic card: **AMD Radeon HD 6570**

Board: **2A9C 1.1**

Bus Clock: **133 megahertz**

BIOS: **American Megatrends Inc. 6.14 11/05/2010**

Processor: **3,20 gigahertz Intel Core i3 550**

---

DRIVERS I HAVE TRIED FOR MY GRAPHIC CARD:

I have tried these drivers so far:

**xserver-xorg-video-ati, version: 1:7.1.0-0ubuntu2**

**fglrx Version: 2:9.010-0ubuntu3**

**fglrx-updates Version 2:9.012-0ubuntu1**

But the fan is still blowing like a maniac.

I have tried to install Linux Mint 15 previously and I have had the same problems with the fan.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know which fan it is? Is is the CPU fan, the GPU fans, or one of the case fans?

If it is the GPU fans, it will most likely stop if you get the appropriate proprietary drivers.

If it is the CPU fan, maybe some setting in the bios can help regulate the speed.

If it is the case fans, it depends on how they are plugged, some cases have an external control, or the fans can be plugged into the motherboard and in this case there may be some settings in the bios as well.

Well since you don't have the issue on Windows, I doubt that it is a setting that you have to change in the bios, since those are common to both OS. So I would guess that it is the GPU? Which drivers are you using? You may want to consider getting the latest proprietary drivers.

Comment: I have tried `xserver-xorg-video-ati, version: 1:7.1.0-0ubuntu2` and also `fglrx Version: 2:9.010-0ubuntu3` and also `fglrx-updates Version 2:9.012-)ubuntu1` but it's still blowing, no matter which driver I use.

Comment: Any idea what to do? Is this problem in every Gnome distribution or just Ubuntu and Mint specific? Should I try KDE or Xfce?

Comment: I doubt that changing distribution would solve it, especially if it is just a variation of Ubuntu with another desktop environment. And I am not very knowledgeable about ATI drivers, I'm sorry.